# How to stop location update for the ads that uses location service

Tags: android, admob

I'm currently using mediation using admob and some ads request for location updates automatically. However, even after the ad has finished loaded, the location updates is not stopped. I can know this by GPS blinking on my mobile phone.
I can only stop the location update the app has stopped completely.

Is there another way to stop the location update more efficiently? So that I would be able to stop the location update right after the ad has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need location in your app you could always remove that permission entirely. It's not required for ad delivery. I don't believe there is any value of explicitly stopping location efforts of some bit of cod that you can't access.